# API level 22 Visual Studio for Android Lollipop 10.1 XHDPI Tablet emulator does not launch

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, hyper-v

I launch my virtual device (10.1 Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet), but waiting long time (forty minutes or more) and nothing shows up, can anyone help me?

I can use API Level 19 with 10.1 KitKat (4.4) successfully, but Api Level 22 can't go into Launcher.

The following is my log from the Visual Studio Emulator for Android

```
0> 2017/4/25 下午 12:03:31 : [Informational] ===== Session Ended =====
0> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 Windows 10 Pro
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Virtualization Version: _asus_ - 1072009
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: gan0wu00086140b     
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Virtualization Product: ux330ua
1> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:31 : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520, Version: 21.20.16.4550
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Warning] Platform config with ID FE19D391-E688-408B-B8CF-E523C4FC602E could not be found.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Warning] Configuration file 'C:\Users\bin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\10.1_Lollipop_(5.0)_XHDPI_Tablet.cfg' was not able to be initialized. The configuration will not be included as a part of the container.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Warning] Platform config with ID FE19D391-E688-408B-B8CF-E523C4FC602E could not be found.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Warning] Configuration file 'C:\Users\bin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\7_Lollipop_(5.0)_XHDPI_Tablet.cfg' was not able to be initialized. The configuration will not be included as a part of the container.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 4 Platforms: 2
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:32 : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:35 : [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:35 : [Informational] Launching Device: 10.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:35 : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:35 : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:35 : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:04:38 : [Informational] Launching emulator...
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:44:57 : [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 10.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet' device. Exit code 0.
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:44:57 : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:44:57 : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd "C:\Users\bin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet.bin"
3> 2017/4/25 下午 12:44:57 : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: Success (0)
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

Comment: I use Api Level 19 with 10.1 KitKat(4.4) is Success , but Api Level 22 cant into Launcher